# The correct syntax of a member which is a class template

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I have a class :

```
      template<typename F1, typename F2, typename F3>
      class A {
        F1 f1;
        F2 f2;
        F3 f3;

        A(F1 f1_, F2 f2_, F3 f3_) : f1{f1_}, f2{f2_}, f3{f3_} {};

         apply_f1() {f1();};
         apply_f2() {f2();};
         apply_f3() {f3();};
         
       }
```

and have the following class where I need to instantiate class A with certain lambda functions. My lambda functions require that I capture `this` since I need certain class members within the lambda. The required interface of the lambdas: `[this](void)->void`

```
    class B {
         A a // How to instantiate it correctly. 
        // .. other stuff.
    }
```

Since I dont know how to instantiate A within `class B` as a member, So far what I have done is creating a static instance of `class A` within the constructor of `class B` like this:

```
B::B(){

   auto f1 = [this]() {....};
   auto f2 = [this]() {....};
   auto f3 = [this]() {....};
   static A a = A(f1,f2,f3);
   SomeEventRegisterClass(a);

}
```

The `SomeEventRegisterClass` will essentially register the instance of `class A` and for now let us just assume that it knows which of the lambdas (`apply_f1, apply_f2, apply_f3)` to invoke on certain events.
In the example above I must declare the variable `a` static because otherwise if just declared locally it will go out of scope right after the constructor has finished. Therefore, when a particular event triggers and `SomeEventRegisterClass` attempts to use the instance of `class A` its lambda's will have been gone out of scope.

The fix with using static above is giving other problems; a simple one when used in the GTEST framework and you are running several tests in one executable, the static will only be defined once. Therefore, I am trying to see if it is possible to create such instance per class and where the lambdas will have same scope as `class B`

Comment: You're just looking for `B::B() : a([this](){ ... },[this](){ ... },[this](){ ... })`???

Comment: This question is not about the syntax of members (because you got that right, obviously), but of how to manage life-time of objects correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare `a` as `A<std::function<void()>, std::function<void()>, std::function<void()>>`. That will let it accept capturing lambdas:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class B {
public:
    B() : a([this] {}, [this] {}, [this] {}) {}

private:
    A<std::function<void()>, std::function<void()>, std::function<void()>> a;
};
```

Note that the `A` constructor must be made `public` too.

Comment: it seems though that the solution require that ´a´ to be a pointer

Comment: @ATK No, the code works just I as wrote it.